# git describe --tags --long adds character to hash?

Tags: git

`git rev-parse --short HEAD` outputs:

```
6aa3158a
```

`git describe --tags --long` outputs:

```
2.3.4-rck1-0-g6aa3158a
```

I see that the latter command adds a `g` to the commit hash. Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [`man git-describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#_examples):

> The "g" prefix stands for
> "git" and is used to allow describing the version of a software
> depending on the SCM the software is managed with. This is useful in an
> environment where people may use different SCMs.

Answer (score 3):

That is the documented behavior of `--long`according to `git-describe(1)`:

```
   --long
       Always output the long format (the tag, the number of commits and
       the abbreviated commit name) even when it matches a tag. This is
       useful when you want to see parts of the commit object name in
       "describe" output, even when the commit in question happens to be a
       tagged version. Instead of just emitting the tag name, it will
       describe such a commit as v1.2-0-gdeadbee (0th commit since tag
       v1.2 that points at object deadbee....).
```

And later on in the same document is an explanation for why it adds the `g` prefix to the hash:

> The "g" prefix stands for "git" and is used to allow describing the
>   version of a software depending on the SCM the software is managed
>   with. This is useful in an environment where people may use different
>   SCMs.